# Save commonly used regex patterns in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to save a commonly used Regex pattern so that I can reuse it between different files? I look through many log files and always need create a mildly complex regex (it's not rocket science but it is a pain to retype) to find errors so it would be good to have a way to recall that without having to save it in a text file and paste it into the search params each time.

Answer (score 22):

Put:

```
source ~/.regexlist.vim
```

into your vimrc.

Do the search.  Decide you might want to use that one again.  Type this literally:

```
:sp ~/.regexlist.vim<CR>
olet MyRegExName = '<C-R>/'<ESC>
:w<CR>
:so %<CR>
:q<CR>
```

Where `<C-R>` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, `<CR>` is <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and `<ESC>` is <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Next time you want to use it:

```
/<C-R>=MyRegExName<CR><CR>
```

Ctrl-R is your friend!  Ctrl-R followed by / pulls up the last search.  Ctrl-R followed by = allows you to enter an expression.

Answer (score 4):

Just press `/` and then arrow up.

Or create commands to invoke regexp search.

```
:command -nargs=0 Errors vimgrep "Error\s*regexp" % | cw 15
```

and then just

```
:Errors
```

Comment: I came here looking for a way to recall previous search patterns. I sometimes search repeatedly for a given pattern, interrupted by a search for a different pattern, and having to re-type the original pattern is annoying. I didn't know that you could access the history with up- and down-arrow. (Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N also work.) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways:

- Create a mapping that does what you want and add it to your `.vimrc`, e.g: `map /foo /[long complicated regex]`. But beware that this will make it hard to search for the literal string "foo", though it can be done with Ctrl-V escapes. Another way is to use some other prefix for your custom regex searches, e.g. `map ::foo /[complicated regex]`.
- Create a function that does the regex search that you want and add it to your `.vimrc`.
- Some combination of the above

Answer (score 2):

If you've started typing a command in vim, including a search or a replace, pressing 'up' should search in your history for recently used commands with the same prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file where you plan to store your regex patterns and keep this open in a separate tab or window as you look through your log files.

To add a search pattern that you just used to your file, type literally:

```
o<CTRL-R>/
```

When you need to use a pattern from your list, move to that line and type literally:

```
yyq/p<CR>
```

You can then switch tabs/windows and then hit n or N to search.